# How to pronounce GUID

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

How do you pronounce "GUID?" Is it one syllable or two?

Comment: Four syllables.

Comment: I personally pronounce it in 4 syllables, but most of people pronounce it in one syllable.

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked over at [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). After all, they are the ones who say it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: oh make no mistake, it did get asked [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940403/) (closed), and then on Programmers (probably deleted, [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/) is the only one I can find right now, but it's closed as well), and then who knows where else.

Comment: @RegDwight: Oh dear! I suppose now we'll get bombarded with more of the same re *Linux*, *GUI*, *SQL*, etc. All effectively "unanswerable", because different people pronounce them differently. And if anyone tells me again we should pronounce *Linux* in a [Linus Torvalds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) accent, I shall scream!

Comment: @FumbleFingers we should pronounce _Linux_ in Linus Torvalds's accent.

Comment: @Tortoise: **Garghhhhhhhhhhh!!!!** (Now the mods will probably have to delete both these comments, but they might spare the one before yours on the grounds it's got an upvote! :)

Comment: I've generally heard "GOO-id" (with a short `i`).

Comment: @HotLicks, I pronounce it as "*Goood*"; or "*Good*" when lazy.

Comment: There isn't a good answer to this because English 'ui' are extremely variable in pronunciation. Ruin, quit, squid, fruit all pronounce it differently. There is an argument given below that "squid" somehow defines the correct pronunciation, however, q in front of u significantly affects its pronunciation. A better rhyme example would be druid of fluid (and also the non rhyming ruin), both of which would support the goo-id approach. Yet we have fruit and suit, suggesting "good". The gwid examples I could find tend to have that confounding q. Me? I've heard both, but goo-id is most common.

Answer (score 46):

[Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) aside, I think it is more common in the IT industry to hear GUID pronounced as:

> [GOO-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560629/what-are-the-pronunciations-of-these-abbreviations) (/ˈguːɪd/)

with a hard G sound (at least in Australia, the UK and Canada).

Comment: In a wide variety of IT contexts all around the US this is by far the most popular pronunciation I've heard. *Gee yoo eye dee* is the next most, and the couple of times I've heard *gwid* everyone turned to stare and try to figure out what the speaker was saying.

Comment: I suspect the two-syllable pronunciation is common due to the two-syllable pronunciation of GUI, *goo-ee*. Goo-ee, goo-id, goo-ee, goo-id.

Comment: I - and all of my IT colleagues - pronounce it like this. Any other version would be most odd.

Comment: I really, really, really hope and wish the guy I used to work with who always says gwid comes here... It's nonsense!

Comment: All the way through college it was pronounced "gwid" by professors and students. So we adopted it and when I got my first job everyone there said it that way too. It wasn't until my second job that I even learned of the GOO-id pronunciation.

Comment: I pronounce it as "gwid" as well. "Goo-id" takes too much time, and "Gee yoo eye dee"? Forget it! I following the same philosophy when pronouncing "SQL" as well. It's "sequel", not "es cue elle".

Answer (score 18):

I go with the 1-syllable version (gwid) that rhymes with squid and liquid and that matches the pronunciation of "languid" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/languid.

Comment: +1 I eventually settle on this if I have to say it enough times to one person in one day. I normally start with G-U-I-D, but I drop to Goo-Id after a while (instantly if the other person says that first). But by late afternoon if I'm still talking about them, they're definitely *"Gwids"*. I know it's only three syllables saved, but "life's too short" and all that!

Answer (score 10):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier):

> pronounced /ˈɡuːɪd/ or the preferred pronunciation /ˈɡwɪd/

So, the single-syllable pronunciation is preferred.

I'll probably continue to spell it out when I come across it despite that fact. :)

Comment: I don't really trust Wikipedia here, who prefers it? I was always more familiar with goo-id and it's also in the top-voted relevant answer over on Stack Overflow

Comment: Initially tempted to vote down because I completely disagree, but won't because the source is listed. In my not inconsiderable experience, it is either spelt out our G-U-I-D, or is pronounce goo-id. My main experience is in the UK, but I've seen dozens of American presentations/seminars/etc, and in each case, these two options have been prevailent. I have *never* heard it pronounced gwid.

Comment: Sorry, I used to link to the [relevant Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560629/what-are-the-pronunciations-of-these-abbreviations) but then edited and reposted the commennt.

Comment: Interestingly, the "preferred pronunciation" comment was only added to the Wikipedia article two weeks ago, with no citation.  I'm inclined to treat it as a bit suspect.

Comment: ...and it is now no longer listed as preferred.

Comment: I prefer the gwid version, personally, as the word guid looks like squid.  I liken the differences in opinion to that of those who say S-Q-L or Sequel when referring to SQL.  Its an acronym so I don't think there's really a correct answer. I think if you were trying to represent the actual words, you'd have to go with guh-you-eyed but that sounds completely stupid to me.

Comment: @user1951, The accuracy of Wikipedia can be either very good or very bad. Always click on the WP talk page to see relevant discussion.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard several pronunciations of this. The frequency I've heard (in London, GB) would be:

1. /ˈɡuːɪd/ (two syllables)
2. /ˈɡwɪd/ (one syllable; my preference)
3. /ˌdʒiː juː ˈaɪ diː/ (four syllables)
4. /ˌɡu(w)ɪ.ˈdiː/ (three syllables: *gooey-dee*)

Comment: I've heard it pronounced with in the same four ways in Michigan, US, and Arizona, US.  Popularity IMX seems to be 3., 2., 1., 4.

Answer (score 3):

I pronounce it with four syllables, as the alternatives sound a little weird to me.

Comment: I try not to pronounce it at all.

Comment: @Mitch , ? How do you try not to pronounce it in a speech?

Comment: @Pacerier I give a sad little choking sound

Answer (score 3):

You can pronounce it as four syllables (/ˌdʒi ju ˈaɪ di/), or like a single syllable (/ˈɡwɪd/).

I don't know if there is a preference between the two pronunciations, but I would expect that the second pronunciation will become the most used one.

Comment: /ˈlaŋɡwɪd/ is the pronunciation of _languid_ given from the _Oxford Dictionary of English_, so it should definitively be /ɡwɪd/.

Comment: (In American English, it would be /ˈlæŋɡwəd/, basing on the NOAD.)

Comment: Hmm. I guess it might be. I'm an American English speaker and I identify the vowel in words like this with /ɪ/, but it doesn't really contrast with /ə/ for me. Sorry, I keep on making comments but I just noticed one more thing! I think the normal stress on acronyms is actually secondary stress on the first syllable (actually, maybe even on all the syllables) and primary stress on the *last* syllable. So I would say /ˌdʒi.ju.aɪ ˈdi/, definitely not /ˌdʒi ju ˈaɪ di/.

Answer (score 2):

I like the version that rhymes with squid (hey, I'm a Southerner), but I understand that it can rub people the wrong way like Bush's pronunciation of nuclear. It seems to me that this may be based both on the linguistic region as well as the technology used. I first heard about this back in the early 1990s from a Microsoft class and they used the squid-guid.

Answer (score 1):

All versions sound a little weird. I hear people say "in using the global ID"; "referencing the globally unique ID" more than I hear G-U-I-D; or guid (squid); or goo-id.

Unfortunately (or fortunately) there doesn't seem to be a consensus.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of shortening something to an acronym is for ease-of-use. It seems logical that it's easier to say a one-syllable word (squid/guid) than endure the agony of having to pronounce a distinct two syllable (fluid/guid). Since GUIDs are in the realm of programming and programming is all about logic, it seems the most logical pronunciation is the single-syllable squid/guid.

Comment: In the same way as how the USA is pronounce _(y)oo-sa_, the UK is _uhk_, an Operating System is _oss_, the Internet Protocol is _ipp_, and Active Server Pages are a type of tree? No. That's not how language works. It may seem the most logical, but it remains by far the least common in actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

On the off-chance there is any interest in the actual traditional word "guid" of Scots English, the pronunciations /ɡyd, ɡɪd/ are given in this dictionary entry: [guid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/guid), though to me, judging from the pronunciation recorded [here](http://forvo.com/word/guid_morning/), it sounds like [ɡɨd] or [ɡɯd].