# Pronunciation of GUI in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, technical

I've heard a lot of Americans pronounce abbreviations like `GUI` as `goo-ey`. Is this the same with British English, or is it more common to spell out the word, like `gee-you-eye`?

Comment: Related: [How to pronunce GUID?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/how-to-pronounce-guid)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think "gooey" is also more common in the UK. I don't recall hearing another programmer spell it out, though I suppose I wouldn't be terribly puzzled if somebody did.

Comment: +1. I too have heard "gooey" far more than gee-you-eye in the UK.

Comment: In my experience, a lot of people coming out of college since the 90s tended to use GUI, perhaps because they had been taught by people for whom the *Graphical* component of the acronym was new/exciting/significant. Since virtually *all* User Interfaces are now graphical, it's hardly worth flagging it up any more. So UI is coming back into fashion - which is a good thing because everyone naturally pronounces that one as "you-eye".

Comment: So I'm all alone with "yooey"?  Just kidding, although I had a non-techie friend who attempted to say GUI as "gwee".  That one we didn't understand for a minute.

Comment: I'm a Brit and I say goo-ey, as do all my techie friends.

Answer (score 8):

As a non-programmer, but auditor of IT quality systems, I hear the non-techies say "gee-you-eye" while the techies say "gooey".

Comment: You mean the non-techies pronounce it "guy"?