# How do you pronounce "GUI"?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pronunciation of GUI in British English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22580/pronunciation-of-gui-in-british-english)

The question is in the title. How do you pronounce the word "GUI"? (Graphical User Interface). Some of my colleagues call it "Guy". Others pronounce it like the "gui" in "Penguin".

I myself take the second approach, but that others take the first approach confuses me.

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of abbreviations in British English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22580/pronunciation-of-abbreviations-in-british-english), see also: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/GUI, [GUI (pronunciation)](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=208003)

Comment: [Pronunciation of GUI in British english](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22580/pronunciation-of-gui-in-british-english) isn’t exactly a duplicate, but pretty much completely answers this question.

Comment: Unless you say Penguin very oddly, I've never heard either of those pronunciations. @xpda explained the only variations I've heard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two common pronunciations:

- Gooey, with a hard G, and
- G-U-I

Comment: These are both correct in "programming circles."

Comment: Thanks. But how do you pronounce "Gooey" ?

Comment: gü-ē -- http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=goo00002&word=gooey&text=\-%C4%93\

Comment: I am a coder and all-around computer geek. I prefer G-U-I, but use and hear Gooey (gü-ē) a lot.

Comment: Pronounced as `/ˈɡuː.i/` or `/ˈɡu·i/` for those who search for the actual pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

A programmer friend of mine pronounces it "gooey".